# Lightning Email template Related Entity Types not populating

Tags: lightning, email-template, related-list

I'm trying to create an email template in lightning. The Related Entity Type dropdown is only loading Contact and lead, not all of the regular objects.
[image: image showing only contact and lead in dropdown]

Comment: Try refreshing without Cache, that should do the trick.

Comment: I tried that but no change. I also tried a new browser and that didn't change anything either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a case with Salesforce and the result was that "Enhanced Email" was disabled. This is the fix:

## ===============
Objects not available under "Related Entity Type" in Lightning email template
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000349235&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1

## However, before you enable this, please review the articles below about Enhanced Email.

Learn about the 'Enhanced Email' and EmailMessage objects
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000313606&type=1&mode=1

## Use Enhanced Email for More Email Functionality
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_enhanced_email_overview.htm&type=5

To enable enhanced email, here are the steps.

1. Click the gear icon on the upper right side, then click Setup
2. On the quick find box on the left, type 'Enhanced Email'
3. Click 'Enable'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My custom object was correct with Activities allowed and "Enhanced Email" setting was enabled. Remove cookies didn't fix.
What finally worked was to disable Enhanced Email and enable it back. My custom object (and a full bunch of others) instantly appeared in the picklist. I was in a sandbox created after the Enhanced Email was activated in the production instance, but there was no Lightning template created yet.

Answer (score 0):

My custom object was correct
Activities allowed and Enhanced Email enabled. Remove the cookies didn't fix.

This worked for me.
Disabled Enhanced Email, re-enable Enhanced Email